# Inconsistent frame title vertical alignment in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to fine-tune a template for my slides with beamer. The problem I have is that when the titles require two lines, there is an inconsistent behaviour. Adding a second line moves the position of the title plus the logo up (emulated in the example below with a rule).

How could I change the template to get a consistent behaviour robust respect to having 1 or 2 lines in the title?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\providecommand\insertframetitle*{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.5cm,wd=\paperwidth]{headline} 
\parbox[b]{.8\paperwidth}{\bf\strut\Large\insertframetitle\strut}\hfill \rule{1.5cm}{.7cm} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{A very very long title that does not fit in one line alone}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A shorter title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `adjustbox`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\providecommand\insertframetitle*{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.5cm,wd=\paperwidth]{headline} 
  \adjustbox{minipage=[r][0.25cm][t]{0.8\paperwidth}}{\bfseries{\Large\insertframetitle}} \hfill \adjustbox{valign=t}{\rule{1.5cm}{.7cm}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{A very very long title that does not fit in one line alone}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A shorter title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can decide with `valign=` whether the image is placed in the middle (m), at the top (t) or bottom (b) of the bounding box of the title. You can also specify whether the short title is set at the top or bottom if you change `[t]` to `[b]` in the `minipage`.

With the `export` option of the package `adjustbox` you can directly use `\includegraphics[valign=m]{}` with the adjustbox environmnet.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\providecommand\insertframetitle*{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.5cm,wd=\paperwidth]{headline} 
  \adjustbox{minipage=[r][0.2cm][t]{0.8\paperwidth}}{\bfseries{\Large\insertframetitle}} \hfill \includegraphics[width=1.5cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{A very very long title that does not fit in one line alone}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A shorter title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add `[b]` to `\parbox`. I removed `\strut` from the solution. Also, it's better to use `\textbf` instead of `\bf`.

Using the following code you'll be able to put the logo at the same place every slide, plus the title won't be too close to (or outside of) the margins.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\providecommand\insertframetitle*{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.5cm,wd=\paperwidth]{headline} 
\parbox[b]{.8\paperwidth}{\Large\textbf{\insertframetitle}}\hfill \rule{1.5cm}{.7cm} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{A very very long title that does not fit in one line alone}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A shorter title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]